# "Rules of inference" when the last premise is a conditional?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Another very basic Discrete Mathematics homework problem.  I don't want the answer as much as I want to understand the question:

> **Problem 7**
>
> > For each of the following sets of premises, what relevant conclusion(s) can be reached?  Explain which rules of inference are used.
> >
> > a) "If I play hockey, then I am sore the next day", "I use the whirlpool if I am sore", "I did not use the whirlpool"
> >
> > b) "I am dreaming or hallucinating", "I am not dreaming", "If I am hallucinating, I see elephants smoking"

Okay, now my problem is with b, which ENDS with a conditional.  I'm pretty confident that I already got a) correct, so let's look at b):

- $p$: I am dreaming
- $q$: I am hallucinating
- $r$: I see elephants smoking

According to the question, we have:

- $p$ V $q$
- ~$p$
- $q\rightarrow r$

The top two premises can be shortened to simply $q$ via "disjunctive syllogism":

- $q$
- $q \rightarrow r$

So...which rule can you use to draw any conclusions from the above, and what is the conclusion?

Using a truth table, if we look at the row where $q$ AND $q\rightarrow r$ are true, this means that $r$ must be true.  So...is the conclusion $r$?  But what rule is that?

Comment: Try modus ponens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your application of the Disjunctive Syllogism in part (b). That gives you the derived premise $q$. Now, you can use **Modus Ponens** and note that from $q$ together with $q\rightarrow r$, we derive that $r$ holds.

Modus Ponens:

$$\begin{align} &\text{Modus Ponens }\\
\hline \\
& q \rightarrow r & q\\
& q & q\rightarrow r\\
\hline \\
\therefore & r &\therefore r\end{align}$$

The argument can be written as $\;q, \;(q\rightarrow r) \models r\;\;$ or as $\;(q\rightarrow r),\;q \models r$

Comment: Note that the *order* in which the two premises occur: $q$ and $q \rightarrow r$, does not matter. Modus Ponens needs both premises, in whatever order, to derive $r$.

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid.  So you're saying the order of the premises can be changed...I had no idea!  Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel stupid! Rules of inference are often presented rigidly; all that has to occur is that the needed premises for a given rule occur prior to "invoking"/applying the rule. Order of given premises doesn't matter either.

Comment: I just started this class, and I really enjoy it, but I've never been very math-minded, so it always takes me an extra explanation or two to really get the concepts.  So far you're 2 for 2 (thanks for the other answer!).  I'll be seeing you around here for sure :)

Comment: If the argument can get written as you put above, then you have a single formula (q∧(q→r) or ((q→r)∧q), and *just one* premise.  Modus ponens requires two premises, and can get put q, (q→r) |= r, or {q, (q→r)}|= r, or (q→r), q|=r, or {(q→r), q}|=r, because you have two premises or a set with two premises in it.

Comment: Yes, Doug, oversight on my part. Thanks, and updated.